# Need to sum the total of Multiplication without using loops

Tags: python-3.x

```
num = 5 
for i in range(1,num):
    for j in range(1,num):
        print(i * j, end="\t")
print()
```

I have this multiplication table and i need to sum all of the numbers given without using loops.
can anyone advise?

Comment: So, this code gives you the correct output, but you need to remove the loops from this code?

Comment: Or, this code doesn't work either?

Comment: Can you please share expected output

Comment: What do you mean by sum all of the numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematics makes any task easier.
Formula is (n(n+1)/2)^2. Just put n = num-1. num-1 because your for loop generates table upto number 4.
Code:

```
>>> num = 5
>>> sum = ((num*(num-1))/2)**2
>>> print(sum)
100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sum all resulting multiplication then add few lines in your code.

```
num = 5 
multi_list = []
for i in range(1,num):
    for j in range(1,num):
        multi_list.append(i*j)

print(sum(multi_list))
#100
```

Comment: The OP wants to solve it without using loops

Comment: He want to sum  without using loops

Comment: They are summed out of the loop not in iteration

Comment: just noticed them being added to the list, sorry mate